# Como renomear arquivos dinamicamente no upload?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código e não sei como alterá-lo para renomear dinamicamente a imagem no momento do upload.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './fotos/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!\n";
}

echo 'Aqui está mais informações de debug:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Você sabe o que seu código faz linha a linha?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim. Compreendo sim. rss

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Tenho dificuldade em implementar o md5 para gerar nomes aleatórios para as imagens.

Comment: Então como acha que muda o nome do arquivo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Acredito que capturando o nome do arquivo, renomeando e enviando para a linha `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)`. Será isso?

Comment: Exatamente. Se olhar a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php), o segundo parâmetro de `move_uploaded_file` é `$destination`, referente ao nome do arquivo final. O nome que der para ele aqui será gravado em disco.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62759/discussion-between-gladison-and-anderson-carlos-woss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [`md5`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.md5.php) junto com a [`microtime][2]` para gerar nomes únicos para cada imagem.

```
<?php

$currentName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$parts = explode(".", $currentName);
$extension = array_pop($parts);

$newName = md5($currentName . microtime());
$destination = "./fotos/{$newName}.{$extension}";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $destination)) {
    // ...
}
```

Desta forma, o novo nome do arquivo será o resultado do `md5` do nome atual concatenado com o retorno de `microtime`, impossibilitando (praticamente) qualquer conflito entre os nomes gerados.